# complex query question

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

scenerio:  I have several events in a CPT called events.  For single events, they use template single-event.php.  I also have guest speakers, in which each one has post in a CPT called speakers.

I'd like to create a query that pulls a custom field from a speaker post with a key's value that matches the event title.

The idea is to display a subset of my speakers on a specific event based on the meta value of the speaker post using a single event template page.

Comment: site is at tlh.villagesquare.us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty easy actually in your `single-event.php` file within the content loop. add this loop where you want your speakers information to show.

```
$event_title = get_the_title(); // This is the title of the current single event page we are on.
$args = array(
  'meta_key'        => 'event_name', // the name of your custom field
  'meta_value'      => $event_title,
  'post_type'       => 'speakers',

);

$speakers_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $speakers_query->have_posts() ) :

  echo '<ul>'; // start your section here

  while( $speakers_query->have_posts() ) : $speakers_query->the_post();

    // echo your speaker content here like name, images, etc.
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';

  endwhile;

  echo '</ul>'; // end your section here
  wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

Comment: Seems like this will work, but I'm having issues dropping it in on my hacked together template which includes several queries and loops.  https://gist.github.com/matthewtlh/d186e26ccea78358e16fd5891ee7cda7

Comment: one of the pages where it outputs: http://tlh.villagesquare.us/event/survival-guide/

Comment: I updated the gist, I put the speakers in a `div` below the read more button in the singlePost `div` check lines 48-73 https://gist.github.com/bynicolas/17e791a2361bfb227d2a6e251ce32806

Comment: Glad I could help, just accept the answer if the solution was what you needed

Comment: actually, I needed to change to: $event_title = get_the_permalink(); I couldn't get the title to work consistantly.  but thanks!

Comment: Well, my answer was based on your question, but you are right, using the title is can become tricky.  The ideal solution would be to use `get_the_ID()` as this won't change and is unique to a post. Cheers!